# How to properly format JSON data in table using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create table to show data received from API. The data is on JSON format and needs to shown on table using AngularJS. I'm able to retrive the required data on view but I'm not able to properly format that in tables. The code is in plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/GZtWlx5aDWvsseSs9ugW?p=preview

View

```
<body ng-app="ShopOpeningHrs">
<div class="container" ng-controller="ScheduleCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="schedule in singledayschedule">
            <td>{{ schedule.morning }}</td>
            <td>{{ schedule.evening }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module("ShopOpeningHrs", []);
   app.controller("ScheduleCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.schedule = data[0];
        $scope.singledayschedule = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.schedule, function(value, key) {
            angular.forEach(value, function(value, key) {
                $scope.singledayschedule.push(value);
            });
        });
    console.log($scope.singledayschedule);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use two ngRepeat loops:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="(shop, schedule) in singledayschedule">
      <td>{{ shop }}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="(day, times) in schedule">
        <div>{{ times.morning }}</div>
        <div>{{ times.evening }}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/CYSqQYFhENQfeeYRFTvp?p=preview